# Operating ROS node from HTTP

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

What i want to do is to send the robot a destination goal from a website I created.

I already have a node that sends the robot the destination.
i'm guessing that i need to make a node that listens to the http port and reads what link has been pressed on the website.
and then start the node that I already have to send the location goal.

but how can i do that?
any help would be much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255070/operating-ros-node-from-http/) by [slevendar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29410/slevendar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [wiki/rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) and the related [RobotWebTools](http://robotwebtools.org/).

I'd also take a look at some of the existing web based interfaces.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0